# Simulatenous computation and data load to shared memory: the case of tiled matrix-matrix multiplication

Tags: cuda

I want to write a matrix multiplication algorithm, basing on the shared memory example from CUDA, that is performing the computing and data load simultaneously. I have the code looking like this:

```
float As[BLOCK_SIZE][BLOCK_SIZE];
float Bs[BLOCK_SIZE][BLOCK_SIZE];
As[ty][tx] = A[aBegin + wA * ty + tx];
Bs[ty][tx] = B[bBegin + wB * ty + tx];
for (int a = aBegin, b = bBegin; a <= aEnd; a += aStep, b += bStep)
{
    __shared__ float A2s[BLOCK_SIZE][BLOCK_SIZE];
    __shared__ float B2s[BLOCK_SIZE][BLOCK_SIZE];
    A2s[ty][tx] = As[ty][tx];
    B2s[ty][tx] = Bs[ty][tx];
    __syncthreads();
    if (a+1 <= aEnd)
    {
        As[ty][tx] = A[a+1 + wA * ty + tx];
        Bs[ty][tx] = B[b+1 + wB * ty + tx]; 
    }
#pragma unroll
    for (int k = 0; k < BLOCK_SIZE; ++k)
    {
         Csub += A2s[ty][k] * B2s[k][tx];
    }   
    __syncthreads();
}
```

But it works slower than the original solution, as the second data loading is performed sequentially with the computation. How can I make parallel?

Comment: one tip: avoid using local memory (when ever you define an array in a kernel without `__shared__` it's LOCAL), it is as slow as global memory

Comment: I was thinking about storing the arrays in the registers - I can't use shared data on all 4 arrays as the compiler returns error concering too much shared data assigned

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid moving data `A` and `B` to local arrays `As` and `Bs`, namely

```
As[ty][tx] = A[aBegin + wA * ty + tx];
Bs[ty][tx] = B[bBegin + wB * ty + tx];
```

You could directly move them to shared memory `A2s` and `B2s`, namely

```
A2s[ty][tx] = A[aBegin + wA * ty + tx];
B2s[ty][tx] = B[bBegin + wB * ty + tx];
```

Also, the data loads

```
As[ty][tx] = A[a+1 + wA * ty + tx];
Bs[ty][tx] = B[b+1 + wB * ty + tx];
```

seem to be unexploited.

Finally, you should move the declaration of shared memory arrays outside the `for` loop and a final assignment to the output matrix was also missing.

Try something like:

```
__global__ void TiledMatrixMultiplicationKernel(float* A, float* B, float* C, int Width)
{
    __shared__float As[BLOCK_SIZE][BLOCK_SIZE];
    __shared__float Bs[BLOCK_SIZE][BLOCK_SIZE];
    int bx = blockIdx.x; int by = blockIdx.y;
    int tx = threadIdx.x; int ty = threadIdx.y;
    int Row = by * BLOCK_SIZE + ty;
    int Col = bx * BLOCK_SIZE + tx;
    float Csub = 0;
    for (int m = 0; m < Width/BLOCK_SIZE; ++m) {
    As[ty][tx] = A[Row*Width + (m*BLOCK_SIZE + tx)];
    Bs[ty][tx] = B[Col + (m*BLOCK_SIZE + ty)*Width];
    __syncthreads();
    for (int k = 0; k < BLOCK_SIZE; ++k) {
       Csub += As[ty][k] * Bs[k][tx];
       __syncthreads();
    }
    C[Row*Width+Col] = Csub;
}
```

Comment: The code I posted was only partial, that is why certain crucial parts of the entire algorithm were missing. As far as I understand your code, it will perfectly utilize the shared data in a load-compute sequence. Still what I am trying to achieve is to hava a load-compute/load next data sequence, to cover the computing under the data load of next parts of data. I assume that some threads will be performing the computing on the existent data while others will be still/already loading data for the next loop steps

Comment: @Matt It is not clear to me how do you mean to overlap computing with memory loads. The above code is a standard implementation of tiled matrix-matrix multiplication using shared memory. In this implementation, each thread loads a corresponding global memory matrix element to a corresponding shared memory matrix location. The threads then synchronize. Finally, each thread calculates an element of the output matrix. Each output matrix element requires the knowledge of full corresponding rows and columns of the input matrix, which means that they should be already inside the shared memory.

Comment: @Matt Conversely, if you want to load and simultaneously accumulate the required vector-vector multiplication results, then you should probably use atomic operations which would then serialize the code.